# How to use more than one multivalued field in solr search

Tags: search, solr, lucene, multivalue

I have documents that has multivalue fields in my solr. I want to make search according to these multivalue fields. 
When I want to query with;

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=*:*&fq=id:FEAE38C2-ABFF-4F0C-8AFD-9B8F51036D8A
```

it gives me the following query result.

```
response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "created_date": "2016-03-23T13:47:46.55Z",
        "solr_index_date": "2016-04-01T08:21:59.78Z",
        "TitleForUrl": "it-s-a-wonderful-life",
        "modified_date": "2016-03-30T08:45:44.507Z",        
        "id": "FEAE38C2-ABFF-4F0C-8AFD-9B8F51036D8A",        
        "title": "It's a wonderful life",        
        "article": "An angel helps a compassionate but despairingly frustrated businessman by showing what life would have been like if he never exis",
        "Cast": [
          "James Stewart",
          "Donna Reed",
          "Lionel Barrymore"
        ],
        "IsCastActive": [
          "false",
          "true",
          "true"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you see I have 2 maltivalue fields that are named "Cast" and "IsCastActive". 
My problem is When I add filters like Cast:"James Stewart" AND IsCastActive = "true" like the following:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=*:*&fq=id:FEAE38C2-ABFF-4F0C-8AFD-9B8F51036D8A&fq=Cast:"James Stewart"&fq=IsCastActive:"true"
```

Solr still gives the same result but "James Stewart" is not active in the document. So, I don't want Solr to response any document acconding to my query. 
  I think I'm doing something wrong. What's the correctly way to do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to filter multifields like that.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "is not active in the document"? You already restricted the search to a single document with **id** match, the rest just repeats the narrowing down.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look much possible in a straight forward manner here in Solr . But i think more effective way would be that you keep your Cast member's name as key , and then associate it with the value as true , or false and then filter on your username as key . Something like this : `James Stewart :["true"]` . Or may be you can use a single field that store cast name and his/her activity status delimited by a colon `.` . Something like this `castInfo:["James Stewart:false","John Sanders:true"]` . You can filter on it then by something like this `fq=castInfo:"James Stewart:false"` .

Comment: Thank you very much for you to share your kindly suggestions. Since solr indexed multivalued fields sequentially, it should also have ability for querying sequentially. Is not it?

Comment: Ya , as far as my experience with Solr , it doesn't have options where you can keep track of indexes in two fields in key value fashion. Though , that being said , we may tweak indexes like above to suit our requirements .

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose an alternative solution to your problem. Such solution stores true/false as [payloads](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Payloads) integers. So the idea is to have a field called *cast* having a definition in the schema like:

```
<field name="cast" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="integer"/>
  </analyzer>
  <similarity class="payloadexample.PayloadSimilarityFactory" />
</fieldtype>
```

The content can be indexed for instance as:

> James Stewart|0
>   Donna Reed|1

where 0/1 is true/false.
Using payloads would also allow you to read directly from the posting list improving your performance on relevant queries. 
[Here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/06/13/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/) you can find an example explaining how to achieve what I explained above.